# how to match data from a linked pages together by web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

i'm trying to scrap some data from a web site and i have an issue in matching the data from every subpage to the data of the main page

for Expample: the main page have a country name "**Alabama Trucking Companies**" and when i enter to it link, i'll found some cities(Abbeville, Adamsville,...etc), i need to clarify every city details (city name and city link) with it's country name

**country names that i scraped from the main page:**

[image]

**city names that i scraped from the sub page:**

[image]

the below code that i used is extracting the data from the main and sub pages individually without matching them to other, So how can i solve this issue please.

**The code that i've used:-**

```
start_time = datetime.now()

url = 'https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/carrier/usa-trucking-companies.php'

page_country = requests.get(url).content
soup_country = BeautifulSoup(page_country, 'lxml')
countries = soup_country.find('div',{'class':'col-xs-12 col-sm-9'})

countries_list = []
country_info = countries.find_all('div',{'class':'col-md-4 column'})
for i in country_info:
    title_country = i.text.strip()
    href_country = i.find('a', href=True)['href']
    countries_list.append({'Country Title':title_country, 'Link':(f'https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com//carrier//{href_country}')})

countries_links = []
for i in pd.DataFrame(countries_list)['Link']:
    page_city = requests.get(i).content
    soup_city = BeautifulSoup(page_city, 'lxml')
    city = soup_city.find('div',{'align':'center','class':'table-responsive'})
    countries_links.append(city)

cities_list = []
for i in countries_links:
    city_info = i.find_all('td',"")
    for i in city_info:
        title_city = i.text.strip()
        try:
            href_city = i.find('a', href=True)['href']
        except:
            continue
        cities_list.append({'City Title':title_city,'City Link':href_city})

end_time = datetime.now()
print(f'Duration: {end_time - start_time}')

df = pd.DataFrame(cities_list)
df = df.loc[df['City Link']!= '#'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

**The expected data to see for every country is the below:-**

[image]

Comment: you should be using scrapy

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: is your goal to eventually parse all the individual trucking companies from each of the city pages as well?

Comment: Yes, it's my goal finally

Comment: Are you not concerned about how long it is going to take you to crawl each and every one of those pages?

Comment: No i don't care, i can wait and i think it'll not taking too much time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251793/discussion-between-mahmoud-badr-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing all of the state links and adding them to a list prior to crawling each of the city pages, what you can do is parse each states extract their link, then immediately follow the link to get all of the cities for that state before moving on the the next state, and then append all the information to one master list at one time.

For example:

```
start_time = datetime.now()

url = 'https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/carrier/usa-trucking-companies.php'

page_country = requests.get(url).content
soup_country = BeautifulSoup(page_country, 'lxml')
countries = soup_country.find('div',{'class':'col-xs-12 col-sm-9'})

data_list = []
country_info = countries.find_all('div',{'class':'col-md-4 column'})
for i in country_info:
    title_country = i.text.strip()
    href_country = i.find('a', href=True)['href']
    link = f'https://www.quicktransportsolutions.com/carrier/{href_country}'
    page_city = requests.get(link).content
    soup_city = BeautifulSoup(page_city, 'lxml')
    city = soup_city.find('div',{'align':'center','class':'table-responsive'})
    city_info = city.find_all('td',"")
    for i in city_info:
        title_city = i.text.strip()
        try:
            href_city = i.find('a', href=True)['href']
        except:
            continue
        row = {
            'Country Title':title_country,
            'Link':link,
            'City Title':title_city,
            'City Link':href_city
            }
        data_list.append(row)


end_time = datetime.now()
print(f'Duration: {end_time - start_time}')

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df = df.loc[df['City Link']!= '#'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: wow... great, another small question, can i make crawl  the companies data from the subpages of cities with the same method?

Comment: yes you will just need to make a request for the city link immediately after extracting it, then parse each companie on that page and append the data for every company before moving on to the next city.  I have a feeling it is going to take a while to do that though

Comment: as you see, the cities links not completed and appeared as a text, so do you know how can i get the full link for each city in an advanced way

Comment: you can use [urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) for that, you would just call it with the `link` variable and the `href_city` variable so just call `urljoin(link, href_city)`  @MahmoudBadr  I still don't think you understand how long it will take though.  When you do just remember what I said about using scrapy.

Comment: Hello Alex, please i tried to scrape the data by beautifulSoup but it takes a very long time and didn't run finally, i read a little about web crawling and scrapy but i can't find tutorials to learn me how to use them on jupter , so can you help me in this

Comment: No... not with jupyter anyway.  You should open a new question.  Other people might be able to help though.  You should open a new SO question. make sure you add jupyter and scrapy as tags